# React / NodeJS - Image saved as Base64 in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, node.js, base64

So I am using a QuillJS editor on my website. The images are now saved in my database as base64. However, it is slowly down my search  since the data in Base64 is incredibly long. I do not need the search to run thru the Base64 code in fact.

What options are there for me?
Here are some that I have thought of:

1. Convert the Base64 code to an image and saved it in a fileserver and replace the address with a pointer
2. Convert the Base64 to a BLOB (Does this help?)

Would it be possible to implement these now at this stage? Or any options  have?

Comment: It would be better to store images (especially if they are large enough) outside DB (in some external storage like Google Cloud Storage or S3) and store only links to them (better relative ones maybe).

Comment: Since I have stored them as base64 on the DB alr, is there any ways I can save them to s3 now?

Comment: Simply write a one-time code to convert and store to S3.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the queries that are "so slow".  It sounds like something simple is messed up.

`MEDIUMTEXT CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin` with Base64  versus `MEDIUMBLOB` does not make much difference, except:

- Note that I specified a lightweight collation.
- BLOB will 6/8 the size of Base64.
- Base64 in a BLOB is essentially identical to that TEXT with ascii_bin.

What will be done with the base64 image?  If you are displaying on a web page, I recommend storing it instead in a file without base64 and use `<img src=...>`.  Then the extra loading is done after the page is built, and in parallel (by the browser & server) if there are multiple images.

"it is slowly down my search" -- We need to better understand how the search is performed to assess which of these is being "slow":

- Collation
- BLOB vs. TEXT
- located in database vs. in file vs. in "cloud server"
- conversion back from base64 to binary
- schema (CREATE TABLE)
- something else